# How to check Default Isolation Level at server/instance level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, configuration, isolation-level

We have installed SQL Server 2017 in 2 servers. Then created 2 databases same way in both servers. In one server I see my database snapshot isolation level is ON and another server its OFF.

[image]

[image]

So, how can I check/change isolation level at server/instance level, so that whenever we create new databases then result should be same?

Comment: Should  be inherited from `model` AFAIK. Though top picture doesn't look like that. When you say "created 2 databases same way" what was that way?

Comment: Right click on database and CREATE new database and then overwrite the database with a backup

Comment: What risk should I have to update both DB to use snapshot level as DBs are recently created?